# Visual Studio 2010 Reporting Services Error Message Data retrieval failed for the subreport

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

After reading this thread here in StackOverFlow: [SSRS Subreport VS2010 data retrieval failed for the subreport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261970/ssrs-subreport-vs2010-data-retrieval-failed-for-the-subreport), I still get the "Data retrieval failed for the subreport". The main report and subreport works fine in BIDS 2008, so it has to be something wrong my .cs or .aspx pages. The code I'm using is below. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

aspx page:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListVisit" runat="server" DataTextField="VisitList"
    DataValueField="VisitID" AutoPostBack="True"  AppendDataBoundItems="true"
    onselectedindexchanged="DropDownListVisit_SelectedIndexChanged"
    DataSourceID="EntityDataSourceVisitDropDown">
    <asp:ListItem Text="--- Select Ship & Visit ---" Value="" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSourceVisitDropDown" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="name=Admiral_NSSAEntities"
    DefaultContainerName="Admiral_NSSAEntities" EnableFlattening="False"
    EntitySetName="vw_VisitList"
    Select="it.[VisitID], it.[VisitList], it.[ShipName], it.[StartDate]"
    OrderBy="it.[ShipName] asc, it.[StartDate] desc">
</asp:EntityDataSource>

<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewerSummeryReportOutBrief" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana"
    Font-Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)"
    WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Width="1139px"
    Height="894px" PageCountMode="Actual" PromptAreaCollapsed="True"
    style="margin-right: 0px">
    <LocalReport ReportPath="Secured\Reports\SummeryReportOutBrief.rdlc">
        <DataSources>
            <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="EntityDataSourceVisitInfo"
                Name="VisitInfo" />
            <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="EntityDataSourceWorkOrders"
                Name="WorkOrders" />
            <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="EntityDataSourcePartsDataByWorkOrder"
                Name="PartsDataByWorkOrder" />
        </DataSources>
    </LocalReport>
</rsweb:ReportViewer>

<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSourcePartsDataByWorkOrder" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="name=Admiral_NSSAEntities"
    DefaultContainerName="Admiral_NSSAEntities" EnableFlattening="False"
    EntitySetName="vw_PartsDataByWorkOrder" >
</asp:EntityDataSource>

<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSourceWorkOrders" runat="server"
    AutoGenerateOrderByClause="True" AutoGenerateWhereClause="True"
    ConnectionString="name=Admiral_NSSAEntities"
    DefaultContainerName="Admiral_NSSAEntities" EnableFlattening="False"
    EntitySetName="vw_WorkOrders" Where="">
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownListVisit" DbType="Guid"
            Name="VisitID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>

<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSourceVisitInfo" runat="server"
    AutoGenerateOrderByClause="True" AutoGenerateWhereClause="True"
    ConnectionString="name=Admiral_NSSAEntities"
    DefaultContainerName="Admiral_NSSAEntities" EnableFlattening="False"
    EntitySetName="vw_VisitInfo" Where="">
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownListVisit" DbType="Guid"
            Name="VisitID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>

</asp:Content>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class Secured_Reports_SummeryReportOutBriefAll : System.Web.UI.Page
{    
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {               
        if (DropDownListVisit.SelectedValue == "")
        {
            this.ReportViewerSummeryReportOutBrief.Visible = false;

            ReportViewerSummeryReportOutBrief.LocalReport.Refresh();             
            ReportViewerSummeryReportOutBrief.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(SubreportProcessingEventHandler);               
        }
    }

    public void SubreportProcessingEventHandler(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
    {

        e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("PartsDataByWorkOrder", this.EntityDataSourcePartsDataByWorkOrder));
    }

    protected void DropDownListVisit_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //In App_Code _TemplateFiles
        Reports.ShowReport(this.DropDownListVisit, this.ReportViewerSummeryReportOutBrief);
    }

}
```

Comment: No replies? Is using entities causing this problem? Anyone?

Comment: I finally solved this problem and posted the answer here: http://forums.asp.net/p/1880535/5336239.aspx/1?p=True&t=634992140884931523